# Issue while passing Table, Column name as Function Arguments

Tags: r, function

CALL

```
dummy_func(bank,job) # never picks the column variable
                     # bank is the table where job is column name
```

FUNCTION

```
 dummy_func <- function(x, y) {


    for (level in unique(x$y)) {

       output<- bank[paste("dummy", level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(x$y ==level, 1, 0)
    }

    return(output)


 }
```

Comment: can you show sample data and output you need

Comment: Have you tried putting y in quotes in the call to dummy_func, e.g., `dummy_func(bank, "job")`?

Comment: @ulfelder: Yup, I did try that.

Comment: @arun kumar mahesh This is basically to create dummy variables for the categorical ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass dataframe & column name as arguments to the function then, replace x$y with x[y] and pass job as dummy_func(bank, "job").

Try this code:

```
library(datasets)
data = iris
colnames(data)
y = "Species"

unique(data[y])

dummy_func <- function(x, y) {
  return(unique(x[y]))
}

dummy_func(data, y)
dummy_func(data, "Species")
```

If you are doing x$y, it tries to look for bank$y and not bank$job.